# BitSet in parallel stream in java

Tags: java, parallel-processing, bitset, atomicinteger

I wanted to ask that how we can efficiently use a thread-safe bitset in parallel java. I mean is there any alternatives for bitset. First, I tried to use AtomicIntegerArray. However, methods like clear or clone cannot be used for AtomicIntegerArray.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please be more specific when you say `clear` and `clone` cannot be used.  That sort of whole-set operation can't really be done concurrently the way you intend, since you'd have to lock the entire collection.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thank you for your reply. Let say the bitset is A. I have a while loop in which I do a sequence of parallel processing. Before entering the parallel process, I want to use A.clear() and A.clone() methods. The content of A is changed in the parallel processing. It seems that A.set() or A.get() operations do not work correctly in parallel processing. Right?

Comment: Using `clear` and `clone` is a little weird -- why do you need to?  Do you need to, instead of creating a new one?  `set` and `get` won't work correctly concurrently, but `AtomicIntegerArray` can do that.